# Giving callback function access to class data members in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, callback

I'm using opencv library in C++ in my project and i'm having problems using the MouseCallback.

I have a class BoardCalibration which has two data members, which I need to use them inside the callback function. You can see this class below:

```
class BoardCalibration{
private:
    Rect _box;  <-- data members i need to upadte inside the callback function
    bool _drawingBox; <--

public:
    BoardCalibration();
    static void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);
    Rect calibrate(Mat& image);
    void drawBox(IplImage* img);
};
```

At the calibrate() method im calling the function which recieves the callback my_mouse_callback function. Code:

```
Rect BoardCalibration::calibrate(Mat& image){
    IplImage * img = new IplImage(image);

    namedWindow("Calibration");

    IplImage *temp = cvCloneImage(img);
    cvSetMouseCallback("Calibration", my_mouse_callback, (void *)img);

    while (1){

        imshow("Calibration", Mat(img));
        cvCopyImage(img,temp);

        if( _drawingBox ){
            drawBox(temp);
        }

        imshow("Calibration", Mat(temp));

        if (waitKey(1)>=0)
            break;
    }

    cout << "calibrated\n";

    delete img;
    return _box;
}
```

And at implementation of my_mouse_callback is:

```
static void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){

    IplImage* image = (IplImage*) param;

    switch( event ) {
    case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: {
        if( _drawingBox ) {
            _box.width  = x-_box.x;
            _box.height = y-_box.y;
        }
                             }
                             break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: {
        _drawingBox = true;
        _box = Rect( x, y, 0, 0 );
                               }
                               break;   
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP: {
        _drawingBox = false; 
        if( _box.width<0 ) { 
            _box.x+=_box.width;  
            _box.width *=-1; 
        }
        if( _box.height<0 ) { 
            _box.y+=_box.height; 
            _box.height*=-1; 
        }

        //drawBox(image, box);  // keep draw on screen
        // display rectangle coordinates
        cout << "TopLeft: (" << _box.x << "," << _box.y << "), BottomRight: (" 
            << _box.x+_box.width << "," << _box.y+_box.height << ")" << endl;
                             }
                             break;
    }
}
```

As you can see i'm trying to reach the _box and _drawingBox members here but because it's static method it does not recognize them. 
How can I solve this problem?? I can't change the prototype of my_mouse_callback otherwise it won't accepted by cvSetMouseCallback.
I also can't define those data member outside of the class because its giving me error that they already defined.
Is there anything else I can try??? 
Thanks.

Comment: did you think about passing a pointer to a c++ object instead of passing a pointer to an image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know anything about opencv but how about something like this

```
struct Helper
{
    IplImage * pI;
    BoardCalibration * pObj;
};


Rect BoardCalibration::calibrate(Mat& image)
{
    .... stuff ....

    Helper * p = new Helper;
    p->pI = img;
    p->pObj = this;

    cvSetMouseCallback("Calibration", my_mouse_callback, (void *)p);

    .... stuff ...   


    delete p;
    delete img;
    return _box;

}


static void BoardCalibration::my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Helper * p = (Helper *)param;
    IplImage* image = p->pI;
    BoardCalibration * pBC = p->pObj;

    switch( event ) 
    {
        case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
        {
            if( pBC->_drawingBox )  // use the pBC pointer

            ... stuff ...


    }

    ... stuff ...

}
```

I don't know the flow of your code to figure out when exactly the helper object should be deleted. So I have the `delete Helper object` code near the `delete img` because if that code was correct, then this would probably be the right place to `delete` the Helper object also. But you need to check that. You need to delete this objects only when you are sure that the callback would have finished running for that call by then.

Comment: Thanks , its seems like the right thing to do.. But Im now having problem compiling it. visual studio says:
1>BoardCalibration.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BoardCalibration::my_mouse_callback(int,int,int,int,void *)" (?my_mouse_callback@BoardCalibration@@SAXHHHHPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: class cv::Rect_<int> __cdecl BoardCalibration::calibrate(class cv::Mat &)" (?calibrate@BoardCalibration@@QEAA?AV?$Rect_@H@cv@@AEAVMat@3@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Etai\Desktop\project\x64\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: taking the deceleration of:
static void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);

out of the class will solve that, but i'm not sure if its ok

Comment: @etaiso: The function body of a `static` class function needs the `classname::` in front of its definition: define it as `static void BoardCalibration::my_mouse_callback(...) { /* body */ }`

Answer (score 1):

OK, i got it. you should do so.it was already successful.

```
1) cvSetMouseCallback("Calibration", my_mouse_callback, (void *)this); // Callback function to give it a this pointer.
2) BoardCalibration* ptr = (BoardCalibration*) param; // ptr pointer to your class.
3) e.g ptr->  _box oder ptr-> _drawingBox //all the private parameters,that you need to use, do this:
```

good luck. I hope it would help you to solve the problem.
Bitte sehr.
Qiuyue Wang.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the details to do it, but I have a idea, that if we could

```
cvSetMouseCallback("Calibration", my_mouse_callback, (void *)img);
```

`param` (object) is the User-defined parameter to be passed to the callback function.
So if we could instead of the `img`, use the `pointer` to point the `class`, maybe we could use `this->` all private parameter or `class`.all public functions.
but I just have the idea, you should try it, maybe successful ...

good luck.
tell me if you made it.
wang.